# YAML File : Reading Yaml file and Writing the file in Same Format

Tags: java, yaml, filewriter, snakeyaml

I have a Yaml file which is in the below format:

connector:
  Key1: Test
  Key2: 22
  Key3: Strringname
  Key4: TestingFucntion

When I am trying to read the file and write it into another file the format is different.
!!package name
connector: {key1: Test, key2: 22
, key3: Strringname, key4: TestingFucntion}

Below is the code which i have used to read the file and write it :

```
             Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             data.put(key1, value1);
             DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();            
             options.setIndent(4);
             options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.AUTO);
             options.setPrettyFlow(true);
             Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
             InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(new File(FIle name));
             Prop cc = yaml.loadAs(in,Prop.class);
             cc.getconnector().setkey3(Strringname);
             Writer fwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(File name), "UTF-8");
             yaml.dump(cc, fwriter);
```

Any suggestions for writing the file in the same format as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK` instead if you want to have the mapping in block style. You also need to tell the `Yaml` constructor about your `options` – right now, they don't do anything.

To remove the root tag and give the options to `Yaml`, add

```
final Representer representer = new Representer();
representer.addClassTag(Prop.class, Tag.MAP);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer, options);
```

This sets the tag of the class `Prop` to `!!map`, the default YAML tag for mappings. This will be omitted unless you're outputting it in canonical style.

---

That being said, the important thing is: **In general, you cannot ensure that the format stays the same**. SnakeYAML does not support that and doing so would technically be a breach of the specification. The keys will always written out in the order you defined in the `Prop` class, not in the order in which they occurred in the original file. Deserialization drops information like whitespace, comments and other formatting details.

If you have any `Map` in your data, the order of the keys will be arbitrary (as in: you cannot define or change it). If the original document contained `...` or `---`, that information will be lost. If the original document contained scalars with `''` or `""`, that information is lost.

You can only define consistent output behavior (i.e. define your options and always use them), but if the input uses a different style, that style will always be lost.